# Design Pattern for handling interrupt data

Tags: c, design-patterns

I am developing a firmware application implemented in C, and I want to know what is a good design pattern for this kind of problem:

1. In main loop, I will get interrupt when I received data from a device using UART communication
2. I would send a AT command and wait for the reply from the device, if the device reply OK, I will send the next AT command until all the commands finish
3. If the device reply NOK (not ok), I will resend the command again

I have considered STATE machine, but I still think the implementation is not elegant, because I was waiting for the response in the main loop, to transit to another state.

Which design pattern should I implement?

Comment: Are there any other time sensitive actions going on in the main loop? Or is the above all it has to do?

Comment: @harmic yup, above is all it has to do

Comment: Have you thought about the observer or the mediator pattern?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos yes, i do, u got any nice implementation of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a simple client-server (consumer-producer) model problem.

**Short Answer: Monitor design pattern.**

**Long answer...**

When you say "I will get interrupt", do you mean that a hardware interrupt will trigger, or a change in execution will occur? In the case of a hardware interrupt, that will be platform specific. [Even something as simple as a keyboard hardware interrupt routine takes a bit of effort to implement](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x1210.html).

If it's the other case, you could just have a main/manager thread, a worker thread, and either:

1. Have the main loop just use mutexes and [spin-lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock), waiting for the worker thread to report data is ready, while the worker thread blocks waiting for I/O to store in a mutex-protected buffer.
2. Rather than spin-lock, use a [condvar](http://cis.poly.edu/cs3224a/Code/ProducerConsumerUsingPthreads.c) ([condition variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_variable)), so you're not burning up the CPU and wasting cycles needlessly.

   ```
   /*
    *  Solution to Producer Consumer Problem
    *  Using Ptheads, a mutex and condition variables
    *  From Tanenbaum, Modern Operating Systems, 3rd Ed.
    */

   /*
       In this version the buffer is a single number.
       The producer is putting numbers into the shared buffer
       (in this case sequentially)
       And the consumer is taking them out.
       If the buffer contains zero, that indicates that the buffer is empty.
       Any other value is valid.
   */

   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <pthread.h>

   #define MAX 10000000000         /* Numbers to produce */
   pthread_mutex_t the_mutex;
   pthread_cond_t condc, condp;
   int buffer = 0;

   void* producer(void *ptr) {
     int i;

     for (i = 1; i <= MAX; i++) {
       pthread_mutex_lock(&the_mutex); /* protect buffer */
       while (buffer != 0)            /* If there is something 
                         in the buffer then wait */
         pthread_cond_wait(&condp, &the_mutex);
       buffer = i;
       pthread_cond_signal(&condc);    /* wake up consumer */
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&the_mutex);   /* release the buffer */
     }
     pthread_exit(0);
   }

   void* consumer(void *ptr) {
     int i;

     for (i = 1; i <= MAX; i++) {
       pthread_mutex_lock(&the_mutex); /* protect buffer */
       while (buffer == 0)         /* If there is nothing in 
                          the buffer then wait */
         pthread_cond_wait(&condc, &the_mutex);
       buffer = 0;
       pthread_cond_signal(&condp);    /* wake up consumer */
       pthread_mutex_unlock(&the_mutex);   /* release the buffer */
     }
     pthread_exit(0);
   }

   int main(int argc, char **argv) {
     pthread_t pro, con;

     // Initialize the mutex and condition variables
     /* What's the NULL for ??? */
     pthread_mutex_init(&the_mutex, NULL); 
     pthread_cond_init(&condc, NULL);      /* Initialize consumer condition variable */
     pthread_cond_init(&condp, NULL);      /* Initialize producer condition variable */

     // Create the threads
     pthread_create(&con, NULL, consumer, NULL);
     pthread_create(&pro, NULL, producer, NULL);

     // Wait for the threads to finish
     // Otherwise main might run to the end
     // and kill the entire process when it exits.
     pthread_join(&con, NULL);
     pthread_join(&pro, NULL);

     // Cleanup -- would happen automatically at end of program
     pthread_mutex_destroy(&the_mutex);    /* Free up the_mutex */
     pthread_cond_destroy(&condc);     /* Free up consumer condition variable */
     pthread_cond_destroy(&condp);     /* Free up producer condition variable */

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the "divide & conquer" principle to split up your problem into manage-able sub-problems. You could use the following patterns in different levels of abstraction:

- You could use a structural, architectural design pattern like the "Layer Pattern" to structure your source code with the following resulting context:

  - increased maintainability (big advantage)
  - decreased performance (neglectable, assuming "enough hardware performance")
- You could use a design pattern addressing scheduling to manage how the
  threading is managed in general. I would recommend a pattern which leads to a
  good responsiveness to incoming asynchronous events ("incoming UART data").
  If you use a realtime operating system (RTOS) you could check if different
  scheduling mechanisms are configurable. One thread could be "receive data"
  (entered after execution of "send data", exited after all data has been
  received), a second thread "command handler" (entered after
  exit of "receive data" thread, exited after command which shall be sent has
  been detemined) and a third thread "send data" (entered after exit of "comand
  handler", exited after all data has been send). The priorities (highest, ..,
  lowest) could be assigned as follows: "receive data", "command handler",
  "send data". Using the "Static Priority Pattern" leads to the following
  resulting context:

  - stability (It is predictable which thread fails in an overload situation.
    Think about receiving something while sending is in progress...)
  - good response to incoming events
  - "unbounded priority inversion" can occur due to blocking resource sharing
    -> requires implementation of a ressource sharing pattern
- You could use the "Critical Region Pattern" (disable task switching) or the
  "Guarded Call Pattern" (~mutex semaphores) to protect the resource
  "UART peripheral".
- The "Observer Pattern" (equals "Monitor Pattern") could be used to manage
  when the active thread changes dependent on wether incoming UART data has
  been detected or not.
- To detect incoming UART data and/or to detect wether all data has been
  transmitted the "Interrupt Pattern" could be used.
  (Assuming the UART supports the related interrupt functionality)
- On the lowest level of abstracion you could use one of the possible "state
  machine" pattern implementations for sending data and for receiveing data in
  the UART driver (UART peripheral states: byte sent/received, errors, etc.).

You can find a lot of summaries and references to examples of the mentioned
and other design pattern in C on eswp3.org. (Sorry, i am not able to
hyperlink more than 2 websites at the moment. I will do so after earning
enough reputations...)